# Making a Console Application ask something and receive input

Tags: windows, visual-studio, console-application, basic

I have Programming in Basic in High School and was tasked with a project in which I was to make a program that says hello to the teacher as well as give a paragraph describing why programming is valuable in today's time.

My initial idea was to make a program that greets and asks the teacher a question on whether they want to know why programming is valuable. When the console asks the question there will be two options: Yes or No. Each having their own text output.

```
 REM Period 6 Class Project for (My Name)
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine
    Dim Yes = input
    Dim No = input
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, would you like to get an explanation as to why programming is valuable?")
    input = Console.ReadLine
    If input = Yes Then
        Console.WriteLine("Well the reason why...")
    End If
```

Where I'm having trouble is actually making the text appear on the application as well as receiving input on whether the code is correct as well.

Comment: It looks like vb.net. is it or you want classic basic?

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

See if .. then .. else

```
input=input.ToLower().Trim()
If input="yes" then
 ...
ElseIf  input="no" then
...
Else
..' unexpected answer
End if
```

Comment: So the code was correct to begin with? I'm not getting any text to show up on the console when I ctrl + f5.

Comment: add Console.Read() at the end so that after output it did not exit immediately